# How do I count all the instances where a certain number is between multiple sets of numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to count the number of times a specific number lies between multiple ranges.

For instance,

```
Specific number: 2.5 (let's say this one is in AD1)

J3=14
K3=22
L3=0
M3=6
N3=6
O3=14
P3=2
Q3=8
```

I need to find how many times 2.5 is between:

```
J3&K3
L3&M3
N3&O3
P3&Q3
```

The reason I would like a formula for this is because I have many "specific numbers" that there are many numbers that I need to test within the same range.

I know I can combine multiple CountIf, but the formula would be way too long.

I remember I can use Sum(CountIf("INSERTFORMULA")) but I think somehow using a combination of Sum(CountIf(Median())) will be simpler to read

```
SUM(Countif(MEDIAN($AD$1,J3,K3)=$AD$1,TRUE),MEDIAN($AD$1,L3,M3)=$AD$1,TRUE),MEDIAN($AD$1,N3,O3)=$AD$1,TRUE),MEDIAN($AD$1,P3,Q3)=$AD$1,TRUE))
```

> Expected result: 2 (i.e. between L3&M3 and between P3&Q3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: (**Edited to correct typo**)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($AD$1>=INDEX(J3:Q3,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7}))))*($AD$1<=INDEX(J3:Q3,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8})))))*emphasized text*
```

The `N(IF(1,{array}))` is a method of returning discontinuous elements of an array using the `INDEX` function.

Depending on whether you want to include/exclude the *bounds* of the ranges when you write *between*, you may want to remove the equal `=` sign from the comparisons.

Comment: Like this logic - hadn't thought of doing this way. You're right - I don't want to include the bounds, so I did remove the = sign. Thank you!

Comment: Ah yes, your edit makes the returned value the correct one (e.g. returns 0 for the M3&N3 pair

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((J3:P3<=AD1)*(K3:Q3>=AD1))
```

Comment: Like the simplicity of this solution, especially with the offset of the ranges so that it does the sumproduct correctly

Comment: @newtovba This will not work in all cases because it doesn't check the relevant `pairs`.  Rather it checks each sequential pair.  For example, given `AD1=0.5` it will return `1` for the match between `M3 & N3`, which is not one that you wanted.

Comment: Extension of this problem (Should I ask a separate question?): Is there a way to embed an "if" statement in this? The reason is because the ranges (e.g. J3&K3) are simplified versions of time (e.g. 22 = 10PM, 6 = 6AM) and the criteria (e.g. AD1) is a specified time (e.g. 2:30AM).

My raw data has 583,443 rows and 19 columns already so I'm not sure if using VBA or Find/Replace to convert each value into "Time" values will take up too much memory (the Excel file is 80MB as is already)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ah I didn't think of testing this data between sequential pairs (I'm on a Mac that doesn't have the "Evaluate Formula" to step into the formula to see how each step in the formula is evaluated.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I'm not understanding why if `AD1=0.5` it wouldnt return the correct result? To me it returns `1` which is because `0.5` is between L3 and M3. Right?

Comment: @JvdV note that you are counting, for example `J3 & K3`, `K3 & L3`, `L3 & M3`.  But if a value falls between `K3&L3`, according to the OP, it should not be counted.  In my case the count differed because of a type when I entered J3:q3 values, but the principal is the same (and I ran into the same problem trying to use that approach).

Comment: Right gotcha now.

Answer (score 0):

divide your formula on two parts:

first one - just calculate MEDIAN($AD$1,J3,K3) and put it in J4 (for example), then drag and copy this formula on the all raw (so in K4 will be MEDIAN($AD$1,K3,L3), and so on)

second one - just summarize raw 4 with formulas - SUM(A4:AA4)
it takes more space on the sheet, but more simple for creation and checking.